# ng cli + bootstrap: how to add bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

i used the "ng cli" to create a new angular 2 project. Now I want to use bootsrap and installed it with npm. So far so good - here is my question:
how can I add bootstrap (which is in the npm packages folder) correct to my angular project, so that the css and js files are built with all the other files.

P.S.: Ng Cli uses webpack, but there is no webpack config. Has the information to be in the "angular-cli.json"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may read more about third party library installation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib).

In your CLI JSON,

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],

"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: this worked fine. thanks! bootstrap is now inlined in a <style></style> tag...do you know how to change this, so that it is built as an external css?

Comment: Currently (with your advise), it looks like:
`<style type="text/css">/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
...etc.

</style>`

I would like to have something like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCompressedBootstrap.css">`

Comment: this is so much easier with ng-cli. just npm install and add refs to the scripts/styles

Answer (score 4):

First you do this

> npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap --save

in your console to download module boostrap on root the projects, **find app.module** in src/app/app.module.ts and later add the components boostrap, it is thus:

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
...
imports: [AlertModule, ... ],
... 
})
```

Go to root projects, and open file **angular-cli.json** y put in where they go styles, the next:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

this is to compile the css, when will you run the command **ng serve**, also you can put others file css and will compiled also.

At this time, you can use the components of boostrap in the html template the any components

```
<alert type="success">hello</alert>
```

to see more, visit the next link: http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/

and... done! XD, sorry for my bad english, I hope this can help you

Note: restart ng serve after all this

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this Native Angular2 directives for Bootstrap project interesting:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap