# Bootstrap styles not applying to my angular 2 project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I added bootstrap css in angular-cli.json - styles. Not applying bootstrap styles to my project. I added in package.json and did npm install. How to resolve this?

angular-cli.json

```
        "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ]
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2"
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng cli + bootstrap: how to add bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923835/ng-cli-bootstrap-how-to-add-bootstrap)

Answer (score 25):

1. No need to update or reinstall your bootstrap just do below mentioned step it will work for you
2. open angular-cli.json inside styles array and specifying the path of bootstrap like this:

   Angular-cli.json:

   ```
   "styles": [
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
       "styles.css"
   ],
   ```
3. Open your style.css and paste this at the top:

   ```
   @import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
   ```

Comment: If anybody is using angular 2+ then you will see the angular.json instead of angular-cli.json. Add the above styles and " run npm install bootstrap --save ".  I have not imported any @import URL in styles.css but still, It worked for me. Don't forget to  " re-run the ng serve"

Comment: This answer solves the issue replacing `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` (which was the correct syntax up to Angular 5) with `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` that is equivalent to `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` (which is the reccomended syntax starting from Angular 6). **BUT** the problem might be that you are writing such a line in the **wrong `"styles": [ .. ]` array**, since there are **two** of such arrays in `angular.json`, as @Goel points out [here below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54389421/4579181)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the data in angular.json.

I thought if I run "npm install bootstrap", it take care for that

Answer (score 7):

In your style.css add following line of code on top and let us know.

```
@import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Also check with following line too

```
@import url("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Added. Remains same.

Comment: create a demo project on  https://stackblitz.com/ and provide link so that I can help properly.

Answer (score 6):

There is two styles declaration in angular.json file. One in Builder section and other one test's builder section. Make sure you are putting it in the right section.

```
"builder" : {
 .....
     "styles" : [                  // It should go here. Around line no. 27
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
 .....
},
"test": {              
 .....
     "styles" : [                  // Not here!
          "src/styles.css",
        ],
 .....
}
```

Comment: I was doing exactly the mistake this answer pointed out, thanks! Please, be aware that changes in angular.json aren't taken into accoun automatically as soon you save the file, as changes in your .ts or .html files do. After editing `angular.json`, if a `ng serve` is running you have to stop it by `Ctrl+C` and then run `ng serve` again.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. I tried to find what was the problem but got no result. I installed bootstrap using

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

which installed the latest bootstrap i.e. ver 4, so I deleted installed bootstrap from node_modules folder and updated dependency in packag.json file to earlier version

```
"bootstrap" : "^3.3.7"
```

and ran

```
npm intstall
```

After specifying the path of bootstrap file in angular style array as

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Step by step:

1. In terminal inside your app directory run:

   ```
   npm install --save bootstrap
   ```
2. Open `angular.json` and search for *styles*. At the beginning of the array paste the path to your `bootstrap.min.css` file

   Should look like this:

   ```
   "styles": [
             "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
             "styles.css"
           ],
   ```
3. Open your `style.css` and paste this at the top:

   ```
   @import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
   ```
4. Restart your server

Answer (score 3):

paste following line of code in .angular-cli.json under styles: []

"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: I added already this line. Still not reflecting bootstrap styles

Comment: Can you paste your cli code here with package.json code?

Answer (score 0):

inside angular-cli.json in

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Comment: I added already this line. Still not reflecting bootstrap styles

Comment: use bootstrap link before style.css may help